# MATLAB- How o save an animated function as a gif

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm using function called "animated line" to create some animated function.
I would like to understand how can I save my function as a GIF to use it elsewhere, e.g. PowerPoint.
I'm trying to use a [gif function](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63239-gif) but I cannot. Could anyone suggest me how to achieve it or how to use correctly gif function?
Here a simple code:

```
    numpoints = 100000; 
x = linspace(0,4*pi,numpoints); 
y = square(x); 
y2 = 3 +square(x+1);
figure 
h = animatedline('Color','b','LineWidth',2); 
h2 = animatedline('Color','r','LineWidth',2);
grid on;
axis([0,12,-3,+6]) 
for k = 1:numpoints 
  addpoints(h,x(k),y(k)) 
  addpoints(h2,x(k),y2(k)) 
  drawnow  


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`imwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) function to create gif.

```
numpoints = 500; 
x = linspace(0,4*pi,numpoints); 
y = square(x); 
y2 = 3 +square(x+1);
f = figure 
h = animatedline('Color','b','LineWidth',2); 
h2 = animatedline('Color','r','LineWidth',2);
grid on;
axis([0,12,-3,+6]) 
for k = 1:numpoints 
  addpoints(h,x(k),y(k)) 
  addpoints(h2,x(k),y2(k)) 
  drawnow  

  % Capture the plot as an image 
  frame = getframe(f); 
  im = frame2im(frame); 
  [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256); 
  % Write to the GIF File 
  if k == 1 
      imwrite(imind,cm,'test.gif','gif', 'Loopcount',inf); 
  else 
      imwrite(imind,cm,'test.gif','gif','WriteMode','append'); 
  end 
end
```

The gif is saved to the file called test.gif.